# Substitute a Li-ion Polymer Battery with AA(A)s

Tags: batteries

My headset broke a few days ago, but the circuit board still functions properly. I want to see if I can re-use it by soldering two 3.5mm female plugs to it, so I can use it with any speaker or headset. The problem is, it used [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4506031/Pictures/Internet/2015-04-07%2020.36.20.jpg) battery, I don't dare to play with those batteries. So I was wondering if it's possible to replace it with 3 AA, AAA, or another more common battery instead.

Comment: I would say they used that battery so that it would fit neatly into their housing. So long as you provide the correct voltage to the circuit and the batteries you use can handle the load, it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: The original battery is easy enough to use and safe enough if used sensibly. You will have a charger for it already. It is by far the easiest solution to your needs. Do any connectins is a place where fire is not a problem. Fire is very unlike;ly if you are careful. LiIon can cause problems but they are 'afe enough' in normal use. Many millions are sold and used yearly without incident. Th % that fail spectacularly is extremely small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make them fit, either 3 AA or AAA would work, but unless you know the circuit, you should stick as close to the existing battery voltage and capacity as possible.  That would mean you have to look at the NiCD or NiMH batteries only, as they are 1.2V per cell.

Given a choice, I'd go with the NiMH option, as not only will you get the 1.2V per cell, or 3.6V in series, but you will also get almost the same capacity as the existing LiP battery currently.

With either of the above batteries, you will need to recharge them externally, or modify the charging circuit of your device.

The above is from making the assumption that you want to stay away from Li-ion Polymer batteries, as stated in your question.  If it is only that particular one that you want to avoid, but don't mind working with them, the best option in an AA or AAA case would obviously be an AA Li-ion Polymer cell. 3.7V per cell, the same capacity, and rechargable by the same circuit as the original.

Comment: Then I think I will get 3 NiMH AA or AAA. When you say capacity, do you mean the mAh? since from what I know, going from 670 to 2050 would make no difference other than making it last longer, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to mAh.  The higher, the longer duration you can use the device.  Li-Ion would have the highest capacity, then NiMh, then NiCd.

Comment: You said "stick as close to the existing battery voltage and capacity", so would it be bad if I had the same voltage but higher mAh?

Comment: No, higher capacity isn't an issue.  Lower could be, that depends, but for headphones, even lower wouldn't be an issue.